# Performance tuning on INNER JOIN with BETWEEN Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have two table's namely `tbl_Small` and `tbl_Large`.

Both the table's I have stored in **Microsoft Azure** and querying from **Microsoft SQL Server**.

--Table 1: Tbl_Small

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Small
(
    cola int
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Small VALUES(1234),(123),(34); 
--1000 rows
```

--Table 2: tbl_Large

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Large
(
    ID bigint identity(1,1),
    cola int,
    colb int,
    colc varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Large(cola,colb,colc) VALUES(0,140,'A'),(150,200,'C'),(1000,15000,'D');
--30 million rows
```

I want to get large table details by joining small table with between condition.

**My try**:

1. Created `NONCLUSTERED` index on tbl_Small(cola).
2. Created `NONCLUSTERED` index on tbl_Large(cola) and tbl_Large(colb).

Query:

```
SELECT s.cola as [Input],l.cola,l.colb,l.colc
FROM tbl_Large AS l
INNER JOIN tbl_Small s ON s.cola BETWEEN l.cola and l.colb
```

**Note**: The above query's execution time is over 10 minutes.

**Edit**: After adding nonclustered index on all columns as said in answer, I got the following execution plan.

Time taken for execution: 5 min

[image]

DTU Percentage graph:

[image]

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Added execution plan in the post.

Comment: What is the tier of the Azure SQL Database? Could you please put the small table first on the join instead of the large?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, `edition = Standard` and `service_objective = S1`, I did swap tables for `JOIN` but didn't work.

Comment: Tier S1 may not be enough. Please see the DTU graph while you run these queries check the DTU graph in the portal. If the DTU graph reaches 100% then throttling may occur

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, Yes DTU percentage is 97%. And I really don't have any idea about this and throttling. Graph screen shot added in question.

Comment: Throttling cause poor performance and connectivity issues. Please run the following query SELECT     
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent',
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent',
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
--service level objective (SLO) of 99.9% <= go to next tier

Answer (score 1):

Your index on tbl_Large needs to be covering i.e. it holds all the data the query needs. If you just create an index on the one column then to get all the data the server will need to use the index and another source to get the other column data. It's probable it won't find it worth the extra work and will ignore the index all together.

For tbl_Large create an index on both col a and col b and also include the value for col c so the code looks like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tbl_Large_cola_colb on tbl_Large (cola, colb)
INCLUDE (colc)
```