# Daily import and export Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I want daily backup data in Azure SQL Database then save as a file in Blob and when my system has an error I can import a backup in Blob to recover the database. In the export case, I found DataFactory to do that but, It is hard to import data. What is the best way to resolve my problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to [schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules) a daily job using [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook). Below you will find a PowerShell runbook you can use on Azure Automation to backup your database to an Azure storage account.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This Azure Automation runbook automates Azure SQL database backup to Blob storage and deletes old backups from blob storage. 

.DESCRIPTION
    You should use this Runbook if you want manage Azure SQL database backups in Blob storage. 
    This runbook can be used together with Azure SQL Point-In-Time-Restore.

    This is a PowerShell runbook, as opposed to a PowerShell Workflow runbook.

.PARAMETER ResourceGroupName
    Specifies the name of the resource group where the Azure SQL Database server is located
    
.PARAMETER DatabaseServerName
    Specifies the name of the Azure SQL Database Server which script will backup
    
.PARAMETER DatabaseAdminUsername
    Specifies the administrator username of the Azure SQL Database Server

.PARAMETER DatabaseAdminPassword
    Specifies the administrator password of the Azure SQL Database Server

.PARAMETER DatabaseNames
    Comma separated list of databases script will backup
    
.PARAMETER StorageAccountName
    Specifies the name of the storage account where backup file will be uploaded

.PARAMETER BlobStorageEndpoint
    Specifies the base URL of the storage account
    
.PARAMETER StorageKey
    Specifies the storage key of the storage account

.PARAMETER BlobContainerName
    Specifies the container name of the storage account where backup file will be uploaded. Container will be created if it does not exist.

.PARAMETER RetentionDays
    Specifies the number of days how long backups are kept in blob storage. Script will remove all older files from container. 
    For this reason dedicated container should be only used for this script.

.INPUTS
    None.

.OUTPUTS
    Human-readable informational and error messages produced during the job. Not intended to be consumed by another runbook.

#>

param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $ResourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $DatabaseServerName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DatabaseAdminUsername,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DatabaseAdminPassword,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DatabaseNames,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageAccountName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$BlobStorageEndpoint,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageKey,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$BlobContainerName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32]$RetentionDays
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'

function Login() {
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        Write-Verbose "Logging in to Azure..." -Verbose

        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
}

function Create-Blob-Container([string]$blobContainerName, $storageContext) {
    Write-Verbose "Checking if blob container '$blobContainerName' already exists" -Verbose
    if (Get-AzureStorageContainer -ErrorAction "Stop" -Context $storageContext | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $blobContainerName }) {
        Write-Verbose "Container '$blobContainerName' already exists" -Verbose
    } else {
        New-AzureStorageContainer -ErrorAction "Stop" -Name $blobContainerName -Permission Off -Context $storageContext
        Write-Verbose "Container '$blobContainerName' created" -Verbose
    }
}

function Export-To-Blob-Storage([string]$resourceGroupName, [string]$databaseServerName, [string]$databaseAdminUsername, [string]$databaseAdminPassword, [string[]]$databaseNames, [string]$storageKey, [string]$blobStorageEndpoint, [string]$blobContainerName) {
    Write-Verbose "Starting database export to databases '$databaseNames'" -Verbose
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $databaseAdminPassword –AsPlainText -Force 
    $creds = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $databaseAdminUsername, $securePassword

    foreach ($databaseName in $databaseNames.Split(",").Trim()) {
        Write-Output "Creating request to backup database '$databaseName'"

        $bacpacFilename = $databaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"
        $bacpacUri = $blobStorageEndpoint + $blobContainerName + "/" + $bacpacFilename

        $exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName –ServerName $databaseServerName `
            –DatabaseName $databaseName –StorageKeytype "StorageAccessKey" –storageKey $storageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
            –AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName –AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password -ErrorAction "Stop"
        
        # Print status of the export
        Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink -ErrorAction "Stop"
    }
}

function Delete-Old-Backups([int]$retentionDays, [string]$blobContainerName, $storageContext) {
    Write-Output "Removing backups older than '$retentionDays' days from blob: '$blobContainerName'"
    $isOldDate = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-$retentionDays)
    $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blobContainerName -Context $storageContext
    foreach ($blob in ($blobs | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $isOldDate -and $_.BlobType -eq "BlockBlob" })) {
        Write-Verbose ("Removing blob: " + $blob.Name) -Verbose
        Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.Name -Container $blobContainerName -Context $storageContext
    }
}

Write-Verbose "Starting database backup" -Verbose

$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

Login

Create-Blob-Container `
    -blobContainerName $blobContainerName `
    -storageContext $storageContext
    
Export-To-Blob-Storage `
    -resourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -databaseServerName $DatabaseServerName `
    -databaseAdminUsername $DatabaseAdminUsername `
    -databaseAdminPassword $DatabaseAdminPassword `
    -databaseNames $DatabaseNames `
    -storageKey $StorageKey `
    -blobStorageEndpoint $BlobStorageEndpoint `
    -blobContainerName $BlobContainerName
    
Delete-Old-Backups `
    -retentionDays $RetentionDays `
    -storageContext $StorageContext `
    -blobContainerName $BlobContainerName
    
Write-Verbose "Database backup script finished" -Verbose
```

Comment: I am using this for weekly backups. Any question just let me know.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, Can you please help me out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832990/performance-tuning-on-inner-join-with-between-condition