# Sync SQL Server onPrem Availability Group to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, azure-sql-database

We have an ERP solution running on an on-premise SQL Server Availability Group.
The new data warehouse has been set up on Azure based on Azure SQL database. We now need a way to update the DWH based on ERP deltas into the cloud.

The challenge:

- we don't want another VM with SQL Server in the cloud for replication
- we have to have delta's because transaction tables and backups are too big to ship to azure daily
- AG primary might failover to another secondary which then would need to know about the last sync

Any ideas on how to approach that and possible architectures/scenarios/tools?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your Hub database is Azure SQL database, you can use [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data).

Azure SQL Data Sync is a service built on Azure SQL Database that lets you synchronize the data you select bi-directionally across multiple SQL databases and SQL Server instances.

You can sync the data from on-premise SQL Server to Azure SQL database with Data Sync.

But **Data Sync doesn't support Azure SQL Data Warehouse**.

Another way maybe you can think about [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).

Using Data factory to sync the data from on-premise SQL server to Azure Data Warehouse. You can [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) and Schedule the pipeline execution daily or weekly, or other time.

You can reference these tutorials:

1. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Data Warehouse by using Azure
   Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)
3. [Syncing on-premise databases to Microsoft Azure Cloud using Azure
   Data Factory](https://www.element61.be/en/resource/building-hybrid-cloud-syncing-premise-databases-microsoft-azure-cloud-using-azure-data)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please help me out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832990/performance-tuning-on-inner-join-with-between-condition

Comment: Hi @MAK,  I have seen your blog.   I'm sorry that I have no idea about how to help you solve  the performance problem for now.

Comment: Okay no problem. :)

Comment: I dont See how you releated to my Always On Availability Group and the challenge of a failover to another server then. Not sure that Azure SQL Data synch can handle that?!